# Authorising a custom web app

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, security

Been googling for a couple of days and haven't really come across any answers as to how facebook / google plus or other websites authenticates their applications (maybe it's because it may be a risk, not sure but still can't find any answers.)

I'm looking to run a website where users can 'install' web applications - Like facebook / google plus does.
E.g: User visits a stack overflow application, it requests permission and get's authenticated.

How would I go about doing this?
I.e how to cross check whether the application is authenticated to the user and the application ID matches the actual application being used to prevent rogue applications using the same ID which is known to be authenticated.

The only way I can think of is checking whether the user has allowed the application or not.
Pseudo: `"SELECT * FROM authorised_applications WHERE user_id = '123' AND app_id = '234'"`
If they have, allow the application to access some data (i.e user name etc).

```
if(mysql_num_rows(pseudo_above)=="1") { allow }
```

However, what if a rogue application uses the same application ID (which, if we presume, is authenticated) and thus can access the data.

I may be over thinking things and confusing myself but I can't really think of how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To authenticate with those services, they use OAuth. I suggest reading this great article:

http://hueniverse.com/2007/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-ii-protocol-workflow/

From what I understand you are looking to set up something similar to that for your web application. I have not used OAuth in conjuction with PHP but I am positive that there are lots of resources out there for using it.

Comment: Thanks Andy; could I use OAuth to authenticate the applications on the same website? I.e the web applications will run 'inside' the website - Like Facebook / Google apps do, but could I still use OAuth to authenticate them?

Comment: I'm *exactly* sure what you're aiming to do. If you want to be able to post to Facebook/Google from within your application then sure you can use two at the same time.